# Is there any possibility to write python selenium script with priorities

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to modify selenium testng script (which has test priorities) to python. Can we use priorities in selenium python too? Can we use one testcase data in another test case (is there any way similar to testng depends on method in python also?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) in python and have to arrange test in numeric order like

```
class TestFoo(TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        ...
    def test_2(self):
        ...
```

But my suggestion to make you automation test independent of each other so that if you need to run your test in parallel then you will be able to do so or you can run any test or in any order which is advantage.

In case if you need to test delete record scenario then first you should create the record then delete it. So in your framework you should have such utilities classes where you should create method for creating record or other that you can used in your test class.

Comment: But my requirement is, i have bash script which collect these test priorities(from testng script) information and update it in cachet. We are plannning to do the same with python